# Get index <li> with jquery if click is on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html list and i need to get index li when click is on its a child element.

I have this:

```
<ul>
<li><a>item 1</a></li>
<li><a>item 2</a></li>
<li><a>item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In other case i would have used

```
$('li').click(function() {
$(this).index();
});
```

But in this case i need get li index when click is on a, so i try:

```
$('li a').click(function() {
$(li).index();
});
```

I expect li index, but just get 0 on console.log

Comment: `$('li a').click(function() { console.log($(this).parent().index());});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.closest()` (in case some `a` is not the direct child of `li`, else `.parent()` is enough) in jquery to do this.

Demo:

```js
$('li a').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('li').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a>item 1</a></li>
<li><a>item 2</a></li>
<li><a>item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent of clicked `anchor` tag and find it's index from the array of `lis`.

```js
$('li a').click(function() {
  const lis = $('li');
  const index = lis.index($(this).parent());
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>item 2</a></li>
  <li><a>item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `parent`

```js
$('li a').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent().index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>item 2</a></li>
  <li><a>item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```